# Is there a function in boost library to generate directly the png file instead of dot?

Tags: c++, boost, graphviz, graph-visualization

I am writing a C++ program which generates a tree with graphviz. I am producing the dot file but I would like to produce the png file directly in my script without using terminal or `system(command)`.

Is there a function in boost which can do this?
It would be something like

```
write_png(Graph g, string filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no. Boost has:

- A [facility](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/graph/doc/read_graphviz.html) for reading Graphviz (.dot) files, as part of Boost Graph Library.
- The [GIL - Generic Image Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/gil/doc/) - Which lets you read and write Portable Network Graphics (.png) files.

but the former produces the structure of a graph, while the latter requires a raster image, not some structured representation. The rendering of a .dot file into a vector or raster image is what the GraphViz library is about, and you would need to use it directly. I'd look at at what [the sources of the `dot` utility](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/) do, and basically reproduce the relevant parts into your own source.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to find the source file of dot and follow your advice.